# SQL query syntax error for Inset Select statement from Temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert data into `TableA` from the query shown here, and the `Insert` and `Select` should run as single statements. But I am getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near If

for the query shown. What is wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

```
INSERT INTO TableA (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)

IF Object_ID ('temp..#Temp') Is not Null
    DROP TABLE #Temp

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    ColA Varchar (100),
    ColB Int
)

INSERT INTO #Temp
    SELECT ColA, ColB 
    FROM TableB

SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
FROM TableC C
INNER JOIN #Temp T ON C.Col1 = T.ColB
```

Comment: `INSERT` needs to be followed by a `SELECT` statement or `VALUES` clause. An `IF`'s expression also needs to return a boolean result (`IF Object_ID ('temp..#Temp')` *what*?).

Comment: Most likely you want `IF Object_ID ('temp..#Temp') IS NOT NULL`  - or you could write much more easily and obviously: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Temp`

Comment: I added IF Object_ID ('temp..#Temp') IS NOT NULL, But Still It gives same issue.
And I already tried Values clause, But It was not working.
Can you frame it and share? Thanks.

Comment: *"But Still It gives same issue"* You haven't addressed the `INSERT`. *"`INSERT` needs to be followed by a `SELECT` statement or `VALUES` clause."* An `INSERT` cannot be followed by an `IF` statement.

Comment: This would be valid as well.  **SELECT ColA, ColB  INTO #Temp FROM TableB**

Comment: The first line should be removed

Answer (score 1):

It is not super clear without table schema's but perhaps you just meant to have

```
INSERT INTO TableA (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
SELECT c.Col1, c.Col2, c.Col3, c.Col4
FROM TableC AS C
INNER JOIN TableB AS B
ON c.Col1 = b.ColB;
```

Comment: Before inserting, I need to use temp table and join with this temp table and insert into TableA.

Comment: Why do you feel you NEED to use a temp table?  This should do the same thing given your example unless you are missing something in your question.  The `INNER JOIN` gets the same values as your temp table would have.

Comment: Not only is this logically the same information is far less complicated and will perform better too as it doesn't first add all the contents of TableB to a temp table.

Comment: I am trying to insert values from Table C, which joins from Temp table and It should insert into Table A. All this statements should run in 1 query. This is the requirement. Thanks.